# How do I implement cmd's auto-tab-completion to python?

Tags: python, windows, console, tab-completion, windows-terminal

```
import os
import subprocess
import tkinter.colorchooser as colorchooser
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import decimal
import time

<...code...>

def execute_command(command):
    print(command)
    global numbers, operators, integer1, integer2, operator, operated
    inputs = command.split()
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    current_directory_files = os.listdir(current_directory)

    if command in current_directory_files:
        return os.path.abspath(command)

    path_dirs = os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep)
    for path_dir in path_dirs:
        try:
            path_dir_files = os.listdir(path_dir)
            for file in path_dir_files:
                if file.lower() == command.lower():
                    return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path_dir, file))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

    for extension in [".exe", ".bat"]:
        executable = f"{command}{extension}"
        if executable in current_directory_files:
            return os.path.abspath(executable)
        for path_dir in path_dirs:
            try:
                path_dir_files = os.listdir(path_dir)
                for file in path_dir_files:
                    if file.lower() == executable.lower():
                        return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path_dir, file))
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass

    if len(inputs) == 3 and inputs[1] in operators:
        try:
            first = int(inputs[0])
            second = int(inputs[2])
            operation = inputs[1]
            if operation == "+":
                print(first + second)
                operated = True
            elif operation == "-":
                print(first - second)
                operated = True
            elif operation == "*":
                print(first * second)
                operated = True
            elif operation == "/":
                if second != 0:
                    print(first / second)
                    operated = True
                else:
                    print("Undefined.")
                    operated = False
            else:
                operated = False
        except ValueError:
            operated = False
    elif len(inputs) == 2 and "+" in inputs[1]:
        try:
            first, second = map(int, inputs[1].split("+"))
            print(first + second)
            operated = True
        except ValueError:
            operated = False

    elif "+" in command:
        try:
            first, second = map(int, command.split("+"))
            print(first + second)
            operated = True
        except ValueError:
            operated = False

    if len(inputs) == 1 and inputs[0].isnumeric():
        print(inputs[0])
        operated = True
        return None  # Added to prevent further processing

    return None


def listdirectory():
    for item in os.listdir():
        print(item)

while True:
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    command = input(f"{current_directory}> ")
    commandlist = command.split()
    executable = execute_command(commandlist[0])
    if command.lower() == "exit":
        sys.exit(0)
    elif operated:
        operated = False
    elif executable:
        subprocess.run([executable] + commandlist[1:])
    else:
        print(f'"{command}" is an unknown command, executable, path file, or a math operation.')
    print("")
```

Sorry for messy code,
I have written an "Alternative Command Prompt" with some fun tools in addition to some really simple commands. I have searched for days trying to find a way to implement cmd's tab completion to my code. Can someone please help?

I tried multiple things such as using pyreadline or readline but none of them seemed to be able to replicate the behavior in Windows's cmd. There are some other modules that *kinda* seemed to work, but it wasn't really functioning the way I wanted.